# Preserving Realm property value when updating object

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm

I'm working on a Swift 3 Realm app and I have this Realm model class:

```
class User: Object {
  dynamic var userName = ""
  dynamic var userURL = ""
  dynamic var userThumbnailURL = ""
  dynamic var isRegistered = false

  var userID = RealmOptional<Int>()

  override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "userID"
  }
}
```

Then I'm adding values as follows. I'm getting them from my server and saving them in the local database:

**Query 1**

```
let user = User()
user.userName = fields["userName"] as! String
user.userURL = fields["userURL"] as! String
user.userThumbnailURL = fields["userThumbnailURL"] as! String                    
user.userID.value = fields["userID"] as? Int
try! uiRealm.write {                   
  uiRealm.add(user, update: true)
}
```

Then when the user finishes the registration I'm updating the specific user in the local Realm database as being a registered user (`isRegistered = true`). This value is only saved in the local Realm database:

```
uiRealm.beginWrite()
let updatingUser = uiRealm.objects(User).filter("userID =  %d", self.userId)
let user = updatingUser.first
book?.isRegistered = true        
try! uiRealm.commitWrite()
```

But my problem is that when the new server response is received and I re-run **Query 1** the `isRegistered` property becomes false. How can I avoid this?

Comment: A RealmOptional value could be a primaryKey?

Comment: Yes, because it's the same primary key from my remote server db I just same them in my local db too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that partial updates of an object cannot be performed by passing an instance of an `Object` subclass to `Realm.add(_:update:)`. The reason for this is that there's no way to represent *don't update this property* for a property on your `Object` subclass. You'll instead want to pass a dictionary to [`Realm.create(_:value:update:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm6createuRxCS_6ObjectrFTMx5valueP_6updateSb_x), where the absence of a given key represents *don't update this property*.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have tried this one 

uiRealm.create(User.self,value:[userName, userURL, userThumbnailURL, isRegistered, userID], update: true) 

But when I remove isRegistered value I'm getting "Array index out of range" error .. 

How can I solve that ?

Comment: It worked. It was my mistake about the array index out of range error. 
thanks a lot for the support.

Comment: @bdash, in my case server response is an array and I am using Codable to map json to objects, how can I partially update such objects?